# TCP Scans vs SYN Scans in port scanning

Tags: ports, network-scanners

What is the difference between `TCP` Scans and SYN Scans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TCP scanning` refers on scanning a target network for `TCP connections` , how you are going to look for the connection defines different techniques. Both `Connect Scan` and `SYN Scan` are types of `TCP Scans` to determine if the probed server has active `TCP connections`

`SYN Scan` is a type of `TCP scanning` where you probe the target network sending `SYN packets`, at all desired ports , to initiate a three-way handshake . The server will respond with `SYN-ACK` for every open port and a `RST response` for closed ones.After that you don't reply to the server to complete the 3-way-handshake and open a connection.

`Connect Scan` is another type of `TCP Scan` similar to `SYN Scan` but this time after receiving a `SYN-ACK` response from the server you reply with `ACK` response completing the 3-way-handshake and establishing a connection to the server, which will take more resources and time to complete.

Comment: So they change in a way of scanning. In addition TCP scan (connect scan) uses the OS system call, connect, to check the port status. SYN Scan uses, a packet with SYN bit set to 1, called SYN PACKET, to check the port status.

Comment: just edited my answer

Comment: Note that, depending on the platform, you may need elevated privileges (root) to perform a SYN scan. Also the scans have different profiles that can create different artifacts on the targets.